# Huggingface AutoTokenizer can't load from local path

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to run language model finetuning script (run_language_modeling.py) from huggingface examples with my own tokenizer(just added in several tokens, see the comments). I have problem loading the tokenizer. I think the problem is with AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('local/path/to/directory').

Code:

```
from transformers import *

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
# special_tokens = ['<HASHTAG>', '<URL>', '<AT_USER>', '<EMOTICON-HAPPY>', '<EMOTICON-SAD>']
# tokenizer.add_tokens(special_tokens)
tokenizer.save_pretrained('../twitter/twittertokenizer/')
tmp = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('../twitter/twittertokenizer/')
```

Error Message:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/z/huggingface_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, pretrained_config_archive_map, **kwargs)
    248                 resume_download=resume_download,
--> 249                 local_files_only=local_files_only,
    250             )

/z/huggingface_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py in cached_path(url_or_filename, cache_dir, force_download, proxies, resume_download, user_agent, extract_compressed_file, force_extract, local_files_only)
    265         # File, but it doesn't exist.
--> 266         raise EnvironmentError("file {} not found".format(url_or_filename))
    267     else:

OSError: file ../twitter/twittertokenizer/config.json not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-662067cb1297> in <module>
----> 1 tmp = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('../twitter/twittertokenizer/')

/z/huggingface_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    190         config = kwargs.pop("config", None)
    191         if not isinstance(config, PretrainedConfig):
--> 192             config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    193 
    194         if "bert-base-japanese" in pretrained_model_name_or_path:

/z/huggingface_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/configuration_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    192         """
    193         config_dict, _ = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(
--> 194             pretrained_model_name_or_path, pretrained_config_archive_map=ALL_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, **kwargs
    195         )
    196 

/z/huggingface_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, pretrained_config_archive_map, **kwargs)
    270                     )
    271                 )
--> 272             raise EnvironmentError(msg)
    273 
    274         except json.JSONDecodeError:

OSError: Can't load '../twitter/twittertokenizer/'. Make sure that:

- '../twitter/twittertokenizer/' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or '../twitter/twittertokenizer/' is the correct path to a directory containing a 'config.json' file
```

If I change  `AutoTokenizer` to `BertTokenizer`, the code above can work. Also I can run the script without any problem is I load by shortcut name instead of path. But in the script run_language_modeling.py it uses `AutoTokenizer`. I'm looking for a way to get it running.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: There is a reported bug in AutoTokenizer that isn't present in the underlying classes, such as `BertTokenizer`.

Answer (score 4):

`AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained` fails if the specified path does not contain the model configuration files, which are required solely for the tokenizer class instantiation.

In the context of `run_language_modeling.py` the usage of `AutoTokenizer` is buggy (or at least leaky).
There is no point to specify the (optional) `tokenizer_name` parameter if it's identical to the model name or path. Therefore, to my understanding, it supposes to support exactly the case of a modified tokenizer. I also found this issue very confusing.

The best workaround that I have found is to add `config.json` to the tokenizer directory with only the "missing" configuration:

```
{
  "model_type": "bert"
}
```

Comment: Copying the `"name_or_path": "foo-bar"` from `tokenizer_config.json` to a brand new `config.json` did the trick. thanks @Ohad

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using nothing that would indicate the correct tokenizer to instantiate.

For reference, see the rules defined in the [Huggingface docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/auto.html#autotokenizer). Specifically, since you are using BERT:

> contains bert: BertTokenizer (Bert model)

Otherwise, you have to specify the exact type yourself, as you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mean AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained can not determine which tokenizer type to instantiate itself? Why AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') works but AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('local/path') doesn't?  Thank you!

Comment: As I said, the `AutoTokenizer` is basing it's choice on the *name* you provide. Since the pretrained models are indicative of which model to choose (i.e., `bert-base-uncased` is referring to a BERT model and so on), you have to store the local model in a folder that *similarly* indicates the used model, i.e., `/path/to/bert-derivative`.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

when loading modified tokenizer or pretrained tokenizer you should load it as follows:

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_to_json_file_of_tokenizer, config=AutoConfig.from_pretrained('path to thefolderthat contains the config file of the model'))